# Manually Plot values stored in Collection in Anylogic Monte Carlo Bayesian Experiment

Tags: anylogic

Good Day Everyone,

In Monte Carlo Bayesian Experiment I am storing data inside a collection (called incidence1). Please see the image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o0Oj.png)

My collection (called incidence1) is collection class: TreeMap, Key is double, and value is also double. See the image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXK0P.png)

Finally, in the Monte Carlo Bayesian Calibration Experiment in Java Actions>After Simulation Run> I am writing the following code

```
incidences1.put(getCurrentIteration(), root.Incidence_Plot);
```

and doing so I get the error when compiling "incidence1 cannot be resolved". See the image below,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjXLY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access `Main` using the `root` keyword:

`root.incidences1.put(getCurrentIteration(), root.Incidence_Plot);`

There is no `incidences1` in your experiment, it "lives" on `Main` so you need to get there first via code.

Comment: Thank You Sir Benjamin. I am facing a new problem called The method put <double, double> in the type TreeMap <Double, Double> for the arguments (int, double). 

I have created another question, can you please check it out. Thanks in advance.